# NSButton "text only" variation that highlight on click?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to find a Cocoa control/button that is "text only" and tracks its highlight when click on.  I've tried several combinations of push button with the Bordered checkbox unchecked, and Type set to as momentary push in, momentary light, and momentary change -- but I get no animation or difference in the running program (when the button is clicked).

Comment: NOTE:  I've seen that for some button types, like "recessed", they will have a SLIGHTLY lighter flyover color, and depending on option, when pressed, they will hold that lighter color momentarily.  Isn't there a way to set the color of the text when pressed so it's more obvious?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried something like this?

[image: 1]]

It gives a button without borders, which highlights text on click, and unhighlights on the next click:

[image]

Is it something like you're looking for?